# python mock property setter while wrapping it

Tags: python, properties, mocking, unit-testing

How do you mock a python property setter while wrapping it (i.e. calling the original setter)? The most straightward way is to access `__set__`, but it's read-only for properties so doesn't work.

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch, PropertyMock


class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value + 1

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self._value = value + 1


class TestSomeClass(TestCase):
    def test_value_setter(self):
        instance = SomeClass(0)
        with patch.object(SomeClass.value, '__set__', wraps=SomeClass.value.__set__) as value_setter:
            instance.value = 1
            value_setter.assert_called_with(instance, 1)
        self.assertEquals(instance.value, 3)
```

There's also the `new_callable=PropertyMock` in the docs, I've tried to combine it with `wrap` but haven't gotten it to work yet.

Comment: Oh good, you noticed that the getter will return `3` in your test case yourself. :-P

Comment: Yeah, I realized that while running the code :)

Answer (score 6):

You need to replace the whole `property` object; you cannot simply replace the setter. this means you'll need to provide a new `property` object, where the setter is your mock wrapper for the original setter (accessed by the `property.fset` attribute):

```
setter_mock = Mock(wraps=SomeClass.value.fset)
mock_property = SomeClass.value.setter(setter_mock)
with patch.object(SomeClass, 'value', mock_property):
    instance.value = 1
    setter_mock.assert_called_with(instance, 1)
```

I reused the `@property.setter` decorator here; it returns a new `property` object with all attributes of the original `property` except with the setter replaced by whatever was passed in; see [How does the @property decorator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work/17330273#17330273)

Comment: Can this be used to patch a property from class in memory? As long as I understand, all these examples do patch an instance... isn't it ?

Comment: @yucer: my answer mocks the property on the class, not a specific instance of that class.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution that re-uses `PropertyMock`, but has the disadvantage of only allowing setters to be mocked in the context.

```
with patch.object(SomeClass, 'value', new_callable=PropertyMock, wraps=partial(
    SomeClass.value.__set__, instance)
) as value:
    instance.value = 1
    value.assert_called_with(1)
self.assertEquals(instance.value, 3)
```

or

```
instance = SomeClass(0)
with patch.object(SomeClass, 'value', PropertyMock(
    side_effect=partial(SomeClass.value.__set__, instance)
)) as value:
    instance.value = 1
    value.assert_called_with(1)
self.assertEquals(instance.value, 3)
```